# Elastic Load balancer returning empty reply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have setup a elb instance that has 80 port open and forwarded to ec2 instance. healthcheck seems to be working fine and I do see request being made from elb to instance in instance's access logs. 
However, when I try to access load balancer via its DNS name either via curl or via browsers - I get empty response.

curl http://DashApp-LB-417259830.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Looked everywhere but not able to identify what is going on in this case.

Comment: Does your EC2 Security group has port 80 open in it?

Comment: Thanks @error2007s, I missed to check port under vpc. It seems working now. Do you have any EC2 url that support IPV6 and show all green here http://validador.ipv6.br/index.php ?

Comment: Well EC2 does not support IPV6 you have to use load balancer if you want a IPV6 URL http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-elb-ipv6.html

Comment: I know that buddy, I just wanted to check any ELB url that said "This site ready for IPv6" here http://validador.ipv6.br/index.php

Comment: Here you go http://imgur.com/a/A8S9U

Answer (score 2):

I can view default ubuntu apache2 introduction page while hitting to the URL and through curl. That means your ELB is working fine. But you may need to reconfigure your web server for view the index page or reconfigure your ELB which points to right apache2 pages.